# Connect my Firebase real-time database to MYSQL database table using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, firebase

I want to retrieve data from Firebase real-time database in my MySQL Database table. I have created my website project using LARAVEL.
Thankyou in Advance!

Comment: Please post what have you done so far to get the data

Comment: I have been searching on the internet for this issue but I didn't find anything that could help me out. Basically I have 3 sensors that provide readings and these readings are stored on firebse at realtime

Comment: I want those readings to store eigther at MYSQL which is localhost or in laravel view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you should go for only firebase database. Connecting firebase with MySQL is not possible. And make more complexities and problems.

Comment: Sir can you guide me through this. I want to show the data that is in firebase in my laravel view. Fetch query.

Comment: You can check out this repo 
https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase
and after that here is a blog that you can connect your firebase with laravel step wise
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/firebase-realtime-database-laravel/

Comment: I followed the guide and got my laravel connected with the firebase database.